# VSCode internal terminal for C not taking any input

Tags: c, linux, gcc, visual-studio-code, terminal

> I work on ubuntu 18.04 with gcc pre-installed and VSCode as default editor, I could easily build and debug my codes untill last night when I suddenly realized that my terminal(internal one in VSCode) is not accepting any input.
> I got the launch.json and tasks.json files from a friend whose VSCode was working fine but didn't make any difference unfortunately

```
This is My launch.json file
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
} 

And Here's the tasks.json file:

{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind" : "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/gcc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help I really don't know what to do with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > I simply reinstalled VSCode, deleted tasks.json and launch.json, moved the whole workspace (only C files) to another location, opened the folder once again, built a file and Worked!
> > I had tried this way once though it didn't work at first!